# Store the value of output of a sudo command ( terminal)

Tags: bash, terminal

So I am trying to script out some tests.

Trying to run sudo xyz. then output would be value=2.

I am trying to store that output to a variable, I am getting an error. when I do:
a= $( sudo xyz).  Error message : sudo xyz is not a valid command.

but I manually enter command sudo xyz. it works fine. How does one save it to a variable.

Comment: Remove the space between equal sign and dollar sign

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It was a syntax issue.

I wanted it to be:

```
a=$(sudo xyz);
```